# How can you contract 'I could'?

Tags: contractions, could

Is it possible to contract 'I could'? Can 'I'd' be used for 'I could' like for 'I would'?

Or, if 'I could' can't be contracted to 'I'd', can it be to 'I'c'd' (but it should be "I c'd" and not "I'c'd", as there's nothing in between "I" and "c") or 'I'ld' (is there some standard convention, like "I'd" for "I would" and "I'ld" for "I could"?)?

Comment: We can say it in a contracted way,  and you might write it as _I c'd_ if you were consciously reproducing someone's colloquial way of talking.

Comment: The point of a contraction is to make shorter, could cannot be made shorter.

Comment: @Lambie Yes itc'd be.  More seriously, the same argument can be made that "would " cannot be made shorter, yet "it'd" for "it would" is standard.

Comment: @JamesK The contractions people use (read writers) are could've, should've and would've. Because there is  a strong then a weak syllable, And two syllables. They lend themselves to it. I find the question a bit naive. I am surprised at KB for her comment. Single words with a one syllable words are not contractable/

Comment: But people do use 'd as a contraction of the single word one syllable word "would". And it has the same stress and rhyme as "could". I don't think the question is naive, but it was very easy to find a list of English contractions so rather a lack of research on the part of the OP.

Comment: @JamesK, I was just asking if there are other contractions or if `I c'd` and `I'ld` are valid. And why should a list contain everything?

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard written (or spoken) contraction for "I could".

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_English_contractions